# The Sphinx puzzle - Heroes of might and magic II

Tags: riddle, game

What is the answer?

> **The Sphinx asks you the following riddle:**
>
> I'm a brook that continues, an old woman or two, when misspelled
> I'm a trinket, do I confuse you?
> I'm inane at each moment, never used by a mime,
> and I'm also a tower in some other time.
> What the HELL am I?!?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> Babel or babble

I can't quite fit all of the question to the answer:

> **I'm a brook that continues,**  babbling brook
>  **an old woman or two**  ??
>  **when misspelled I'm a trinket**  bauble
>  **do I confuse you?**
>  **I'm inane at each moment**  to babble is to talk inanely
>  **never used by a mime** a mime does not talk
>  **and I'm also a tower in some other time.**  Tower of babel.